# Unable to connect to MQ using amqmdnetstd.dll

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I am getting an exception "MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE" while executing the below code while using **amqmdnetstd.dll** from NuGet Package Manager.
However when I use **amqmdnet.dll**, I do not encounter any exceptions.
The reason I want to stick to amqmdnetstd.dll is because it is available in NuGet Package and I can deploy the code over any server without having to worry about installing IBM Websphere in every server I deploy.

```
        string QueueManagerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueManagername"];
        Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
        properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Connection"]);
        properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PortNo"]);
        properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Channelname"]);
        properties.Add(MQC.MQCA_TOPIC_NAME, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Queuename"]);
        properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);

        queueManager = new MQQueueManager(QueueManagerName, properties);
```

Is there any reason why there is difference in behaviour of the two dll's?

Comment: Can you check the `AMQERR01.LOG` on the queue manager you connect to and see what error if any is present.  Look in the user that is running the .NET apps's home directory under the sub-directory `IBM\MQ\data\errors` and see if you find an `AMQERR01.LOG` that may show more details on why you are getting the `MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE`.

Comment: @JoshMc unfortunately I have no control over the queue whatsoever. I am only provided with the queue name and other configs required to connect to queue and read from it. It's working fine with amqmdnet.dll

Comment: By control of the queue, I assume you mean the queue manager?  Even with no control you can surely reach out to the MQ admin and ask them if they see any errors on the AMQERR01.LOG.  I gave a second suggestion which has you are in full control over, can you review and see if you see any logs being created on your own machine?

Comment: I'll post it again if it was not noticed: Look in the user that is running the .NET apps's home directory under the sub-directory `IBM\MQ\data\errors` and see if you find an `AMQERR01.LOG` that may show more details on why you are getting the `MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments at the end of this [IBM knowladge Center page : Installing IBM MQ classes for .NET Standard](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q132490_.htm#q132490_). There appears to be an issue with **v9.1.4** of **amqmdnetstd.dll** - the one published on [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBMMQDotnetClient).

Most people seem to be getting around the problem by downgrading. This requires you to download the previous version of the client and include the dll in your project as IBM only started publishing to nuget from v9.1.4.

Comment: version 9.1.5 of the Nuget package works and we've been using it in a production environment without issue.